# Getting OTP from SMS in iOS does not work in specific languages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sms, autofill

I have added the autofill feature to my application, and complied to all the necessary rules to make it work (included the word "passcode", made the UITextfield as .oneTimeCode). The SMS contents are like:
*"123456 is your OTP(One time passcode) which you can use to login with the App"*.

When the SMS is received in English, the OTP is successfully shown as a suggestion in the keyboard and autofill works with no problems. However, when the SMS language is different (Albanian in my case), the OTP does not show as a suggestion.
I don't think this is a language support problem as it worked with an SMS in Turkish. What I noticed are two different cases when opening the SMS from the Messages App:

**English content case**:

The OTP in the SMS is greyed out and underlined.  When tapping it the code, i get the option to copy the code

**Albanian content case**:

The OTP in the SMS is blue and underlined. When tapping the code, i noticed that it was being recognised as a phone number instead, because i was shown the option to call it

I am not sure whether these cases are related to the core problem, but i want to know if anyone has encountered this problem before and if there is a workaround. Thanks in advance